# Cookies with Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a cookie that is shared to both my plugin and my contentPage but
I didn't find any way to do so. (I know how to create cookie but its not appear on the cookie list of the tab page).
any ideas?

Comment: Please be clearer: what is the expected output? perhaps you are looking for the local storage? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: cookie stored and filtered by `path, host and domain` (`document.cookie` returning to you cookies available for current `document.location.href`) if u want share some data between content script and background/event page use *chrome.storage.local* [extension api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local)

Comment: currently my app can set a cookie. I can open the resources and see its value. now I want this cookie to be exist also on my page cookies list.

Answer (score 0):

From the `chrome.cookies` [API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies): "*To use the cookies API, you must declare the "cookies" permission in your manifest, along with host permissions for any hosts whose cookies you want to access.*"

The API docs have a few code snippets, and a link to some more complete examples.